# How to form a character byte by assigning values to each of the bits?

Tags: c

I have a C function which accepts a character. I need to extract as well insert bits into that character. I am clear with the extraction part. Can anyone give me an idea of how to insert values to bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you want to check the nth bit of a char:

```
int checkBit(char c, int n) {
    return c & (1 << n);
}
```

To set the nth bit:

```
void setBit(char *c, int n) {
    *c |= 1 << n;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pretty vague question, I would suggest you brush up on bitwise operators. This should point you in the right direction.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html

Answer (score 2):

Since you requested for idea and not exact implementation:

Here is what you can do,

Iterate over each bit and set it as required.

You can set the nth bit (0 indexed as follows)

```
byteVal = byteVal | (1<<N);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the Nth bit in a character to 1, you need to `OR` it with the value `1` shifted to the left by N positions:

```
c |= 1 << N;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, simply resort to binary operations. The following function should do exactly what you want, but with a simple interface:

```
char set8 (char ch, int index) {
   if (index >= 1 && index <= 8) {
        return (char)(ch | (1 << index - 1));
   }
   return ch;
}

int n = 0;

set8(n, 1); // Returns 1
set8(n, 2); // Returns 2
set8(n, 3); // Returns 4

...

set8(n, 9); // Returns n (0)
```

The function uses bitwise-OR to toggle the specified bit. If the index specified is outside the range of a byte (8 bits), then it simply returns the character passed in.